# Help to resolve integral with roots?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve this integral but I have not been able to solve it yet. The first step I have done is to make an abstraction of the exercise:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(  \sqrt[b]{1-x^{a}} - \sqrt[a]{1-x^{b}} \Big) dx $$
And I used change variable like this: $1-x^a=e^{t}$

$$  \ln(1-x^a) =\ln(e^t)  \\   
             \ln(1)-a\cdot \ln(x)  =t \\ -a\cdot \ln(x)=t \\ \ln(x)=-\frac{1}{a}\cdot t \\
x=e^{-\frac{1}{a}\cdot t} , \quad dx=-\frac{1}{a}e^{-\frac{1}{a}\cdot t} dt$$ .

Now I'm only going to work with only one of the two elements of the integral. And I would like to know if I'm going the right way

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(  \sqrt[b]{1-x^{a}} \Big) dx = \\
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[b]{1-e^{-t}} \cdot \Big(-\frac{1}{a}\Big)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{a}\cdot t} \;dt \\
 \Big(-\frac{1}{a}\Big) \int_{0}^{1}   
(1-e^{-t})^{\frac{1}{b}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{a}\cdot t} \; dt \\
\Big(-\frac{1}{a}\Big) \int_{0}^{1} (e^{-\frac{b}{a}\cdot t}-e^{-t -\frac{b}{a}\cdot t})^{\frac{1}{b}} \; dt \\
\Big(-\frac{1}{a}\Big) \int_{0}^{1} (e^{-\frac{b}{a}}-e^{-\frac{a+b}{a}\cdot t})^{\frac{1}{b}} \; dt$$

But i dont know now how to continue. Is there some other method that I haven't used?.

Comment: $\ln(1 - x^a)$ is _not_ equal to $\ln{1} - a \ln{x}$.

Comment: $I_1=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[b]{1-x^{a}} dx=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[b]{1-x^{a}} \frac{x^{a-1}}{a}\frac{a}{x^{1-a}} dx$. Making change $x^a=t$ you get$I_1=a\int_{0}^{1} t^{1/a-1}(1-t)^{1/b}dx$$=aB\big(1/b+1;1/a\big)=a\frac{\Gamma\big(1/b+1\big)\Gamma\big(1/a\big)}{\Gamma\big(1/b+1/a+1\big)}$. In the same way you can evaluate the second integral.

Comment: $y=\sqrt[a]{1-x^b}\Rightarrow x=\sqrt[b]{1-y^a}$